# How to take look up values from a look up table using SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a scenario as described below need to create a SSIS Package for that.

I have 3 COLUMNS in source table which needs to be entered in destination table.

But all these columns has to be looked up in the look up table of destination database and then enter their ID's in the destination column.

For example

Source table has 3 columns with values

```
idnum   static type timedimension   geography   modified date
1        price      daydate         france  8/12/2015
2      RetailpRICE  WEEK            ITALY   9/12/2014
```

I want a package which looks up the column values with the matchin ID and populates in the destination table...

I know we can use the LOOKUP transform to update the data for one single column in destination table what about the other columns which I need to insert along with the lookup insertion.

How can I achieve this ? Also is there a way to pull only the recent data from the source table using modified date column values

Comment: Are you actually connecting to MySQL as you've tagged or did you mean SQL Server, which does not use the mysql as a tag (or mssql)

Comment: im connection to SQL server studio 2012.

Comment: Do you understand that using the `mysql` tag is confusing at best and at worst can lead to a solution based on an incorrect architecture?

Comment: Next time i  avoid these issues.. thanks for the input.

Comment: Can you explain your question in more detailed steps and name the columns you lookup and maybe give info about these lookup tables?

Answer (score -1):

Use a different lookup for each lookup table that you need to reference to get the Ids.    So if each of your columns that you want IDs for gets its ID from a different table, then you need to use three lookups, one after the other, until you have all three IDs.

Comment: Yes i do have used three look up shapes as you mentioned.. How can I insert them all together into the destination table ? I tried with the Union ALL shape but it is inserting as a seperate look up ID's into the destination table.(For eg: each look up shape picks 2 ID values from the lookup table and if I do the union all then at the destination 6records get inserted instead of inserting 2 RECORDS with the column values)... Can this be sorted out ?

Comment: You put them one after the other in the same dataflow stream, and then there is no need to UNION ALL or anything else.   All three of the columns added by the lookup will be available at the final destination table.   Each lookup should be adding a value to your row, not creating new rows by picking 2 values.

Comment: Glad to hear it.   You can close this question by clicking the checkmark to the left of the top of this answer.

Comment: @TabAlleman - Gowtham is asking how to get all columns along with lookup output..

Comment: @GowthamRamamoorthy - any solution for this? I am surprised community is unable to understand the question.. without explaining which part is not understood

Comment: @HydTechie I suggest you create a new question if you have a question about this.  This question is seven years old, and unlikely to be followed by the community.   Based on my earlier comments, I believe this question was resolved, but Gowtham never closed it.